# how do i redirect my URL in with folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

my url

```
www.mysite.com/content
```

How can i redirect my site if type wrong URL like this

```
www.mysite/contentfasfsa(any letter)
```

That would redirect to original site www.mysite.com/content/ how could i do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit your .htaccess file. There are two ways for doing this :

```
1. ErrorDocument 404 /content (Your home page)
   This will redirect all the error 404 to your homepage.

2. RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^ www.mysite.com/content [L]
   This rewrite rule will redirect broken links to your homepage.
```

Try them out.

Comment: Thank it helps me a lot

Comment: @taliffsss My pleasure :)